# Creating registry keys from a csv file in powershell not working

Tags: powershell, csv, registry

I am trying to write a powershell script that creates registry keys and their values from a csv file containing the list of the registries that are to be created.

The Problem is that i am getting an error. Only the registry keys are created and not their properties.

---

This is my csv file "listeRegistre.csv" :

```
Path,Name,Value,Type
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet",(Default),"[ProductName].exe",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe",(Default),"[ProductName]",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe",LocalizedString,"[ProductName]",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities",ApplicationDescription,"description",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities","ApplicationIcon","[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductName].exe,0",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities","ApplicationName","[ProductName]",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\FileAssociation","","",""
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\StartMenu","StartMenuInternet","[ProductName].exe",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\URLAssociations","ftp","[ProductName]URL",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\URLAssociations","ftps","[ProductName]URL",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\URLAssociations","http","[ProductName]URL",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\URLAssociations","https","[ProductName]URL",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\URLAssociations","url","[ProductName]URL",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\DefaultIcon","(Default)","[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductName].exe,0",String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\InstallInfo","HideIconsCommand","[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductName].exe "--hideicons,String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\InstallInfo","IconsVisible",1,DWord
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\InstallInfo","ReinstallCommand","[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductName].exe" --reinstall,String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\InstallInfo","ShowIconsCommand","[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductName].exe" --showicons,String
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\shell\open\command","(Default)","[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductName].exe",String
"HKCU:\Software\Classes\[ProductName]HTML\shell\open\command",,"",""
```

The headers of the csv file :

- Path : path of the registry key to be created
- Name : name of the property item to be created
- Value : value of the property "Name"
- Type : type of the property (REG_SZ OR DWORD)

Following a screenshot of my csv file

[image: this is my csv file]

---

This is the powershell script :

```
 $registries = import-csv "c:\registre\listeRegistre.csv"

    ForEach ($registry in $registries){

        $registryPath = $($registry.Path)
        $name = $($registry.Name)
        $value = $($registry.Value)
        $type = $($registry.Type)
        Write-host $registryPath $name $value $type

        #If the registry doesn't exist : creates it 
        #Else creates only the properties
        IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath)){
            New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
            New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null}
        ELSE {
            New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null
        }

    }
```

The data is properly displayed on screen.

I am getting the following **errors** :

```
New-ItemProperty : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Name », car il s'agit d'une chaîne vide.
Au niveau de ligne : 15 Caractère : 51
+         New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name <<<<  $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
```

The translation of the first lines of the error  : 
New-ItemProperty : can't associate Name to arguments as Name is empty.

```
Test-Path : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Path », car il s'agit d'une chaîne vide.
    Au niveau de ligne : 13 Caractère : 19
    +     IF(!(Test-Path <<<<  $registryPath)){
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

The translation of the first lines of the error  :
Test-Path : can't associate arguments to Path as Path is empty.

Following a screenshot of my script

[image: This my script]

Following the errors associated with my script :

[image: errors part1]

[image: errors part2]

**Please could somebody help me, i am new in powershell and i am stuck very badly as this code works with one registry key like this :**

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\ScriptingGuys\Scripts"

$name = "Version"

$value = "1"

$type = "DWORD"

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath)){

    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null}
ELSE {
$value = "5"

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
}
```

the above script works as the registry key and it's property both are created without problem.

---

**So in response to the problem above i used the script posted by bert** :

```
$registries = import-csv "c:\registre\listeRegistre.csv"

    ForEach ($registry in $registries){

        $registryPath = $($registry.Path)
        $name = $($registry.Name)
        $value = $($registry.Value)
        $type = $($registry.Type)
        Write-host $registryPath $name $value $type

        #If the registry doesn't exist : creates it 
        #Else creates only the properties
        IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath)){
            New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
            New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null}
        ELSE {
            New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null
        }

    }
```

But when lauching this script i **get lots of errors** which i fail to understand,Please could you help me in this matter.

The errors i am getting  :

```
Get-ItemProperty : Le membre « (default) » est déjà présent.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 15 Caractère : 24
+         if ((Get-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name $Name) -ne $Null)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ExtendedTy
   peSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,
   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[Product Name].e
xe.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[Product Name].e
xe\DefaultIcon.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[Product Name].e
xe\shell\open\command.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\[Product Name]\DefaultIcon.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\[Product Name]\shell\open\comm
and.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\[Product Name]\DefaultIcon.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\[Product Name]\shell\open\comma
nd.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\[Product Name].exe\sh
ell\open\command.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : La propriété (Default) n'existe pas dans le chemin d'accè
s HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\[Product Name].exe.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ((Default):String) [Remove-Item
   Property], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

Remove-ItemProperty : Accès au registre demandé non autorisé.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 18 Caractère : 23
+             Remove-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-
null
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_CURRENT_US....htm\UserCh
   oice:String) [Remove-ItemProperty], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.Powe
   rShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand

New-ItemProperty : Accès au registre demandé non autorisé.
Au niveau de C:\registre\registry_scriptv3.ps1 : 20 Caractère : 19
+         New-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Value $Value -Prope
rtyType $Type -ErrorAction Stop -Force | Out-Null
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_CURRENT_US....htm\UserCh
   oice:String) [New-ItemProperty], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.Powe
   rShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
```

I would really appreciate your help,

Thank you .

Awaiting for your reply

Comment: Hi, check the value of `$registry`, your CSV import may be the culprit.

Comment: The error occurs in line 15 at char 51, is this line part of your above sample? The last line of your sample won't work with no name etc.

Answer (score 2):

First off all your path to the csv file is not correct! as stated by Randip.
Second the last line in your csv file

```
"HKCU:\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[ProductName].exe\Capabilities\FileAssociation","","",""
```

does not have a name/type/value so you can not create a itemproperty without a name!

here is a little code change I suggest:

```
$CsvFile = 'c:\listeRegistre.csv'



    import-csv -Path $CsvFile | ForEach-Object {
        $Name = $_.Name
        $Path = $_.Path
        $Type = $_.Type
        $Value = $_.Value
        IF(($_.Path -ne '') -and (!(Test-Path -Path $Path))) # If the registery path doesn't exist, create it
        {
            New-Item -Path $Path -Force | Out-Null
        }
        if (($Path -ne '') -and ($Name -ne ''))# if the property name is provided
        {
            if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name $Name) -ne $Null)
            {
                Remove-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Force | out-null

            }
            New-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name "$Name" -Value $Value -PropertyType $Type -ErrorAction Stop -Force | Out-Null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, as i tried your code but it is still not working. I am still getting the following errors : **Test-Path : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Path », car il s'agit d'une chaîne vide.
Au niveau de ligne : 5 Caractère : 25
+     IF(!(Test-Path -Path <<<<  $_.Path)) # If the registery path doesn't exist, create it
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand**, how do i do  this ?

Comment: Can you please provide the full file u use.  
Because the error stating that Path is empty suggests you have a line like "","","","",""
or a trailing blank line in your csv file

Comment: i ve updated my post, i ve put the whole csv file in my post. when i added **Write-host $registryPath $name $value $type** this line of code in the loop, it is displaying all the data in the csv file line by line. So i dnt understand. Have you any idea how i could achieve to add a number of registry keys and their properties in powershell ? maybe you ve done it before...

Comment: I 've tried but it works fine on my end.  Did you tried my code in a test file?

I think we 're missing some info.
Can you set up a little test script with my code?

Comment: Can you try it your self with the sample csv without replacing the placeholders?

Comment: what do you mean by without replacing placeholders? whts a placeholder ?

Comment: [ProductName] is a place holder I gess, the problem is in the difference between your example file and the real file.  Are there special characters in the Product name or manufacturer

Comment: no no, wht i ve posted here is exactly the same csv file that i want to use.

Comment: i ve added a screenshot of my csv file, script and the errors that i am getting .

Comment: I 've changed the sugested code, can you try this now?
It is because there are blank lines at the bottom of your file

Comment: i tried your code and it worked fine. But the thing is it created the registry keys a second time. Wht i want is if the registry key exists it only adds the property that doesn't exist not a second key. and wht did you add to make this work . Actually i am not very experienced in coding.

Comment: I added the 2 ($_.Path -ne '') parts in the code, to skip empty Paths (blank lines)

I will  update the seccond IF with a check if the parameter doesn't exist

Comment: I have made the change

Comment: why ve you imported the csv file twice and could you please comment the if with the Get-itemProperty since i don't understand the meaning of it. thnx

Comment: I corrected the copy mistake (twice import csv)

the if checks if the Item property exists if it does, remove it!
afterwards (re)create the property.

Comment: oh ok, i thought you could just modify the property value directly.

Comment: I think you can, but in your code you use, New-ItemProperty.
I think New is not meant to change values. you shoud use a other approach.

Comment: i ve executed the script you posted and i am getting some errors which i fail to understand, could you please explain tht to me, i ve updated the new errors in my post. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in the input only. Please cross check that.

**Instead of this:**

```
$registries = import-csv "c:listeRegistre.csv"
```

**Do This:**

$registries = import-csv 'c:\listeRegistre.csv'

This should do your work.

Also check the output you are getting for each component inside the loop using *write-host $registry* and *write-host $registryPath*

Hope it helps.

Comment: hello Randip! i changed import-csv "c:listeRegistre.csv" by import-csv 'c:\listeRegistre.csv' but still i am getting the same error.   plus i added Write-host $registryPath $name $value $type and it is displaying the correct information. how do i do this ?

Comment: Can you post the error what you are getting now. and also post the data sample of the csv file

Comment: the errors are the same that i have written in my post : saying path and name are both empty.

Comment: Errors alright ..Send the sample of csv file. Want to see hows the input format

Comment: you mean send by mail ? where can i find you mail id ?

Comment: @cruzo : not mail. you can post it as pic here . Else you can dump in pastebin and share the link for that so that I can have a view to that